# Autoboxed when assigned integer or character for the Character Wrapper

Tags: java, autoboxing

why we can assign both int value and a char value to Character Wrapper type. Autoboxing means boxing for the corresponding wrapper but Character is not the corresponding wrapper of int. It is Integer

why both of these statements are possible

```
Character character = 'a';
Character character2 = 3;
```

Comment: Without looking up the Java Language Spec (which I recommend as the primary source of information on such questions) I would guess that there is an implicit conversion from int to char. You can write `char c = 3`, too.

Comment: Because char is an integral type. char b = 'a'+1;

Comment: Why you can assign a value up to 65535 to a Wrapper Character class. what are all 65535 represent ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is treated as an `ASCII` value, if you assign int value to Character.

Below **4 approach** result in *same* output.

```
Character character2 = 'e';
```

---

```
Character character2 = 101;
```

---

```
int i = 101;
Character character2 = (char)i; // casting int to char i.e. treat it as ASCII value
```

---

```
Character character2 = (char)101;
```

---

```
System.out.println(character2); // Prints e
```

**Note:** You can refer this [`ASCII Table`](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: you can assign a combined value of 32,767 (lower-) + 32,768(upper+) which is 65535. so you can assign something like this Character character =65535; then what why are all the 65535 values for

Comment: Added the link into the answer. 65535 will result in `?` when you print it. As it is not assigned to any character.

Answer (score 0):

3 is not necessarily an int. it is short type. Both char and short are 16 bit in length

Comment: It is not exactly a `short` value as well I guess. This would give compilation error:  `short cs = 3; char cc = cs;`

Comment: but this compiles `char cc = (char)cs;`

Answer (score 0):

It is the **ASCII** value assigned to the character.

In the first case

```
Character character1 = 'a';
```

**The `character1` is directly assigned a character value.**

But in your second statement:

```
Character character2 = 3;
```

**character2 is assigned the ASCII value of 3 which is `?`**

Comment: then what represents 65535 when you can assign it also to a Character